# Determine best size for images in an given space

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

What I want:
image = a square bitmap with Width = Height
all images are EXACTLY the same size

I've got a program which draws images on a container.
In this case the images are generated bitmaps.
The dimensions of the container are generic (the same size as the clientsize of the form).

I want the images laid out in rows and columns. But the drawing part should calculate how many rows and how many columns fit the best for the given amount of images and resize the images to make them fit.

What I've got:
code for resizing the object where the images are in

```
    public void ResizeScreen(Size newSize)
    {
        this.size = newSize;
        InitializeObjectSize();
    }
```

code for resizing the images

```
public void InitializeObjectSize()
        {
            int objectSize;
            int spacing = 10;
            if ((this.size.Height - 2 * spacing) <= (this.size.Width - ((objects.Count + 1) * spacing)) / objects.Count)
            {
                objectSize = this.size.Height - (2 * spacing);

            }
            else
            {
                objectSize = (this.size.Width - ((objects.Count + 1) * spacing)) / objects.Count;
            }
        foreach (Object object in objects)
        {
            object.Size = objectSize;
        }
    }
```

Code for drawing the images/
This one centers the images horizontally and vertically and draws them.

```
public void DrawObjects()
    {

        if (objects[0].Image != null)
        {
            drawImage = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
            System.Drawing.Graphics tempGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(drawImage);
            int spacing = 10;
            int totalwidth = this.size.Width; //- ((objects.Count * spacing) + spacing);
            int totalUsedWidth = objects.Count * objects[0].Size + ((objects.Count * spacing) + spacing);
            int realign = (totalwidth - totalUsedWidth) / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
            {

                int startxposition = (objects[i].Size * i + 10 * i + 10) + realign;
                int startyposition = (size.Height - objects[i].Size) / 2;
                tempGraphics.DrawImage(objects[i].ObjectImage, startxposition, startyposition);
            }
            tempGraphics.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a little unclear precisely what you're asking, could you provide a bit more information about how you want the images to be laid out and what the dimensions of the container will be? Posting code and then asking answerers to pick-through it will get your question voted out of existence. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some more information.

Comment: well that's the point. the dimensions of the container are generic (the same size as the clientsize of the form).

I want the images laid out in rows and columns. But the drawing part should calculate how many rows and how many columns fit the best for the given amount of images (all images are EXACTLY the same size by the way)

Hope this clerifies it a bit more.

Comment: This is normally done by constraining either the width or the height and filling the space and scrolling the in non-constrained direction. Even if you constrained the Aspect Ratio that would be something to work with. Without constraining the container in anyway you might as well just have a single line of images.

Comment: There still enough here to do it right.  If you have 10 images, how would you define "best fit"?  5x2?  2x5?  4x2 with 2 on a 3rd row?  You are asking for a subjective answer to a vague question.

Comment: @James Barras I've got a single line of images now that got's scaled so they'll fit in the row. But what I want is that it makes some rows from it so the images can be bigger.

Comment: @DonBoitnot: If i got 10 images I want the images to be as big as possible on the given screen depending on the width and height on the form.

Comment: So, for a given number of squares and a given bounding space you want to calculate the biggest possible square size and how many rows and columns that is

Comment: yeah exactly! sorry I didn't thought it was that hard to explain what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it.
It's a brute force method.(it will try all combinations and pick the best

```
        public void SetObjectSize()
        {
            int objectSize = 0;
            for (int objectsPerRow = 1; objectsPerRow <= objects.Count ; objectsPerRow++)
            {
                int rows =(int)Math.Ceiling(((double)objects.Count) / objectsPerRow);
                int horizontalSize = (this.size.Height - (rows * spacing + spacing)) / rows;
                int verticalSize = (this.size.Width - (objectsPerRow * spacing + spacing)) / objectsPerRow;
                int newSize = horizontalSize < verticalSize ? horizontalSize : verticalSize ;
                if (newSize > objectSize)
                {
                    this.rows = rows;
                    this.objectsPerRow = objectsPerRow ;
                    objectSize = newSize;
                }
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need the aspect ratio

```
Double aspectRatio = height/width;
```

Using the aspect ratio you need a calculation which will turn a number of columns into a number of squares.

```
Double squares = columns * columns * aspectRatio;
```

You need the smallest number of squares which is greater than the number of squares you have, so invert the formula.

```
    Double columns = Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(squares / aspectRatio));
    Double rows = Math.Ceiling(columns * aspectRatio);
    Double actualSquares = rows * columns;
    Double squareWidth = width / columns;
    Double squareHeight = height / rows;
```

Note that due to the `Math.Ceiling` your squares won't quite be square. You'll need to take the smaller number and calculate the remaining to form a margin, you can then pad each square or form a border

Comment: I can follow the redenation And I'll try to fix it probably tommorow.
The only thing I don't get is calculating the squares. The amount of squares is given. or is it for something else?

Comment: Yes the amount of squares is given. It's the number of images you want to show

Comment: the squares are the images. or do you mean something else with squares?

Comment: Yes the squares are the images

Comment: I didn't manage to make yours working. However I've got it working with the method I posted as an answer